# Query Execution failed when running Mongo command through bash script

Tags: javascript, mongodb, bash, mongodb-query

I am executing a bash script to create a database on mongo server. So I am executing mongo command through a java script file.

Currently I am executing below query at my local host but execution is getting failed

```
mongo localhost:27017 C:\Database\newDataBase\createDB.js
```

what is the correct mongo query?

Comment: File `C:\Database\newDataBase\createDB.js` does not look like `bash` - rather looks like Windows. Maybe try `"C:/Database/newDataBase/createDB.js"`

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Sorry it is not bash script it is normal mongo query .I get below error
E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @C:/Mongo/newDB/createDB.js:1:4
failed to load: C:/Mongo/newDB/createDB.js

I checked path of java script file where mongo qyery is present, and path is correct ..So not sure why it can not load java script file

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error in your `createDB.js` script. Can you provide the script?

Comment: I have written below query in java script file
db = db.getSiblingDB('newDB')
mongorestore --host=localhost --port=27017 --gzip --archive=C:\backup --nsInclude 'n2aenv.*' --nsFrom 'n2aenv.*' --nsTo 'newDB.*'

Basically in script I am creating a new database and restoring data to new database using mongo restore command

Answer (score 0):

That's not a javascript. You cannot call an external executable from javascript.

Simply run the `mongorestore` directly:

```
mongorestore --host=localhost --port=27017 --gzip --archive=C:\backup --nsInclude 'n2aenv.*' --nsFrom 'n2aenv.*' --nsTo 'newDB.*'
```

Comment: I am writing a spring boot application for backup data .So before mongo store i need to create a new db and then will store back up data at new data base by mongo store..So how can i achieve that through this spring boot application.

Comment: What do you mean by "create a new db"? Databases and collections are created automatically if the don't exist.

Comment: i need to back up data every qtr .So i need to create a new database and store the data there by mongo dump and restore. But mongo restore command does not create new database automatically.

Comment: Of course `mongorestore` can create new database, it's the default. You can even control behavior with options `--noIndexRestore, --noOptionsRestore, --restoreDbUsersAndRoles` Why do you need to "backup" into a new database? Just keep the dump file and restore it, when required.

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding what you mean by "create a new database", please elaborate.

Comment: actually every qtr I need to create a new data base and restore dumped data to this newly created data base using mongo restore query. So here in java script i am trying to write mongo query to create a new data base and then storing dumped data to this newly created data base using mongorestore command. So could you please help me how to write script in java script to create new data base and restore data on new database using mongorestore query

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "create a new data base"? You can run mongorestore on a completely empty MongoDB deployment. Your requirements are not clear. You can simply start a new mongod instance - but why do you like to restore a dump into it?

Comment: thanks Wernfried Domscheit it got solved .No need to create a java script file mongo restore command automtically creates a database if does not exist