# Running a javascript having mongodb queries from mongodb shell

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am running mongo query from a java script file ,But execution is failing with below error

```
[js] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @C:/Database/newDataBase/createDB.js:1:4
failed to load: C:/Database/newDataBase/createDB.js
```

I checked path of java script file it is correct. I am not sure why it can't load java script file.

Currently I am executing below query at my local host

```
mongo localhost:27017 C:\Database\newDataBase\createDB.js
```

What would be correct mongo query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query Execution failed when running Mongo command through bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68296195/query-execution-failed-when-running-mongo-command-through-bash-script)

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I would have closed the old ticket but I saw some one is in process to answer my query..So please allow me to keep that old ticket alive until getting complete answer from him .Or else his and my effort will be wasted.